# Factory pattern appropriate?

Tags: php, design-patterns

Well,

I have a problem (ok, no real problem, but I wanna try out something new) with creating objects. Actually I have some orders, which contains a list of orderitems.

These orderitems are used and so spreaded in the whole application, and I need a way to create them. The main problem is, I want to be able to create these objects in many different ways.

Actually I do this in the class constructor and check if the argument which is given.
(I'm using php, so there is no overloading support from the language as you surely know :))

A simple and quick Example

```
class foo {
    protected $_data=null;
    public function __contruct($bar){
        if (is_array($bar)){
            $this->_data=$bar;
        }
        else {
            $dataFromDb=getDataFromDatabase
            $this->_data=$dataFromDb;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, if I want to create my object by giving another type of parameter, lets say a xml-document encapsulated in a string I need to put all this stuff in my constructor.
If the process for creating an object is more complicated, I eventually need to create a seperate method for each type,  I want to initiate. But this method is only called when this special type is created. (I think you got the problem :))

Another problem comes to mind, if I need more parameters in the constructor to create a concrete object, I have modify all my code, cause the contructor changed. (Ok, I can give him more and more parameters and work with default values, but that is not what I really want).

So my Question is, which pattern fits this problem  to solve my creation of a concrete object. I thought about creating a factory for each way I want to create the concrete object. But I'm not sure if this is a common solution to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF its only the signature of the constructor changing i would do it like so (a la the Zend Framework universal constructor):

```
class foo {
  // params

  public function __construct($options = null)
  {

    if(null !== $options)
    {
       $this->setOptions($options);
    }
  }

  public function setOptions(array $options){

    foreach ($options as $name => $value){
      $method = 'set' . $name;
      if(method_exists($this, $method)
      {
         $this->$method($value);
      }
   }

   return $this;
  }
}
```

And this essntially means all your constructor parameters are array elements with named keys, and anything you want used in this array during initialization you create a setter for and then its automatically called. The down side is the lack of effective hinting in IDEs.

On the otherhand if you want to have specific constructors then i might go with a factory but still use much the same approach:

```
class foo {

  public static function create($class, $options)
  {
     if(class_exists($class))
     {
        $obj = new $class($options);
     }
  }
}
```

Of course you could alternatively use PHP's reflection to determine how to call the constructor instead of just injecting an arbitrary array argument.

Comment: Wow, the code in example one is very nice. Took me a while to understand it, but I will definatly using it, if it matches any problem i got.
But in the concrete scenario I think your second example is the way I want to do it.
So I create an abstract base-class of my current one and do the specific things in seperated classes for each way I want to create my object.
Thank you, your examples really enlightenend me.

Comment: Glad it helped... please not i changed the constructor a bit... i was in a hurry earlier :-)

Answer (score 1):

you could simply make it a factory with optional params :)

```
class Example_Factory
{
    public static function factory($mandatoryParam, $optionalParam = null)
    {
        $instance = new self;
        $instance->setMandatory($mandatoryParam);

        if ($optionalParam !== null) {

            $instance->setOptional($optionalParam);
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    public function setMandatory($in)
    {
        // do something....
    }

    public function setOptional($in)
    {
        // do some more...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you too for that quick answer. It's a nice solution too, but I think I cannot adept that for my concrete problem, cause I don't have mandatory and optional things. The values I give to the my concrete constructors cannot be splitted in these two categories.

Comment: well it's not limitted to mandatory/optional, it's just an exmaple, you can also have only 1 param or 5. the pattern is to call methods on the new instance depending on the input data :)